# Running electrical on outside of house

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, brick

I need to convert an outlet to 230V 15A for a window AC. Unfortunately the outlet is on the second floor, outside wall of a solid brick house.

I’m considering punching a hole through the back of the cavity behind the box to run the new line. It would then be conduit from there down the side to near the electrical panel where it would re-enter the house.

Is this safe and reasonable? What kind of conduit do I need?

Comment: What is the outlet right now? Is it on its own homerun from the main panel, or on a branch circuit shared with other outlets?

Comment: It’s the tail end of a branch. I’ll be able to pull the line out from the neighboring box easily enough. I just don’t have a good way to run a line all the way back to the panel from there.

Comment: If that entire branch were converted to 230V, and could no longer be used for your minimum required number of 120V receptacles (i.e. within 6' of any point on the wall)... would there still be a legal number of 120V receptacles?

Comment: No. Every outlet in that room is on the same circuit. Not that this house follows that rule anyway. The house pre-dates electricity. Outlets tend to be somewhat randomly placed.

Comment: Is the existing box metal or plastic?

Comment: The existing box is the standard blue plastic outlet box you find everywhere.

Comment: I've gone another route with this, so the original question is now irrelevant for my specific purposes. However, I'll leave it open if it is of enough general interest.